# BERT DataLoader: Difference between shuffle=True vs Sampler?

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I trained a DistilBERT model with DistilBertForTokenClassification on ConLL data fro predicting NER. Training seem to have completed with no problems but I have 2 problems during evaluation phase.

1. I'm getting negative loss value
2. During training, I used shuffle=True for DataLoader. But during evaluation, when I do shuffle=True for DataLoader, I get very poor metric results(f_1, accuracy, recall etc). But if I do shuffle = False or use a Sampler instead of shuffling I get pretty good metric results. I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with my code.

Here is the evaluation code:

---

```
print('Prediction started on test data')
model.eval()

eval_loss = 0
predictions , true_labels = [], []

for batch in val_loader:
  b_input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
  b_input_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
  b_labels = batch['labels'].to(device)

  with torch.no_grad():
      outputs = model(b_input_ids, 
                      attention_mask=b_input_mask)

  logits = outputs[0]
  logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
  label_ids = b_labels.detach().cpu().numpy()
  
  predictions.append(logits)
  true_labels.append(label_ids)

  eval_loss += outputs[0].mean().item()


print('Prediction completed')
eval_loss = eval_loss / len(val_loader)
print("Validation loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
```

out:

```
Prediction started on test data
Prediction completed
Validation loss: -0.2584906197858579
```

I believe I'm calculating the loss wrong here. Is it possible to get negative loss values with BERT?

For DataLoader, if I use the code snippet below, I have no problems with the metric results.

```
val_sampler = SequentialSampler(val_dataset)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, sampler=val_sampler, batch_size=128)
```

Bu if I do this one I get very poor metric results

```
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
```

Is it normal that I'm getting vastly different results with shuffle=True vs shuffle=False ?

code for the metric calculation:

```
metric = load_metric("seqeval")
results = metric.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
results
```

out:

```
{'LOCATION': {'f1': 0.9588207767898924,
  'number': 2134,
  'precision': 0.9574766355140187,
  'recall': 0.9601686972820993},
 'MISC': {'f1': 0.8658965344048217,
  'number': 995,
  'precision': 0.8654618473895582,
  'recall': 0.8663316582914573},
 'ORGANIZATION': {'f1': 0.9066332916145182,
  'number': 1971,
  'precision': 0.8947628458498024,
  'recall': 0.9188229325215627},
 'PERSON': {'f1': 0.9632426988922457,
  'number': 2015,
  'precision': 0.9775166070516096,
  'recall': 0.9493796526054591},
 'overall_accuracy': 0.988255561629313,
 'overall_f1': 0.9324058459808882,
 'overall_precision': 0.9322748349023465,
 'overall_recall': 0.932536893886156}
```

The above metrics are printed when I use Sampler or shuffle=False. If I use shuffle=True, I get:

```
{'LOCATION': {'f1': 0.03902284263959391,
  'number': 2134,
  'precision': 0.029496402877697843,
  'recall': 0.057638238050609185},
 'MISC': {'f1': 0.010318142734307824,
  'number': 995,
  'precision': 0.009015777610818933,
  'recall': 0.012060301507537688},
 'ORGANIZATION': {'f1': 0.027420984269014285,
  'number': 1971,
  'precision': 0.019160951996772892,
  'recall': 0.04819888381532217},
 'PERSON': {'f1': 0.02119907254057635,
  'number': 2015,
  'precision': 0.01590852597564007,
  'recall': 0.03176178660049628},
 'overall_accuracy': 0.5651741788003777,
 'overall_f1': 0.02722600361161272,
 'overall_precision': 0.020301063389034663,
 'overall_recall': 0.041321152494729445}
```

UPDATE: I modified loss code for evaluation. There seems to be no problem with this code. You can see the new code below:

```
print('Prediction started on test data')
model.eval()

eval_loss = 0
predictions , true_labels = [], []

for batch in val_loader:

  b_labels = batch['labels'].to(device)

  batch = {k:v.type(torch.long).to(device) for k,v in batch.items()}
  
  with torch.no_grad():
      outputs = model(**batch)

      loss, logits = outputs[0:2]
      logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
      label_ids = b_labels.detach().cpu().numpy()
  
      predictions.append(logits)
      true_labels.append(label_ids)

      eval_loss += loss


print('Prediction completed')
eval_loss = eval_loss / len(val_loader)
print("Validation loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
```

Though I still haven't got an asnwer to the DataLoader question.
Also I jsut realised when I do `print(model.eval())` I still get dropouts from the model in evaluation mode.

Comment: Can you show in the code how you are calculating `f_1, accuracy, recall `

Comment: Just added it now

Comment: I added another update for loss value. It seems to work fine now but I still haven't got an answer for DataLoader problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the answer is pretty simple:

"I saw my father do it this way, and his father was also doing it this way, so I'm also doing it this way".

I've looked around a lot of notebooks to see how people were loading the data for validation and in every notebook I saw that people were using the Sequential Sampler for validation. Nobody uses Shuffling or Random Sampling during validation. I don't exactly know why, but this is the case. So if anyone visiting this post was wondering the same thing, the answer is basically what I quoted above.

Also, I edited the original post for the loss problem I was having. I was calculating it wrong. Apperantly Bert reutrns loss at index 0 of the output (outputs[0]) if you also feed the model the original labels. In the first code snippet, when I was getting the outputs from the model, I was not feeding the model with the original labels, so it was not returning the loss value at index 0, but returning only the logits.

Basically what you need to do is:

```
outputs = model(input_ids, mask, label=label)
loss = outputs[0]
logits = outputs[1]
```

Comment: The reason you don't need to shuffle data when doing validation is not because everyone is doing it like this. There is actually a good reason. During validation you don't do back propagation and you don't update the model's weights, so the order in which you pass the validation data to the model is completely irrelevant. Hence why there is no point in shuffling them, and we can just feed data in the original order sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calculating the loss correctly. Firstly I wonder why you use the mean of the logits as loss, but that might be sth task specific that I am not familiar with.
But you are definitely not accumulating the losses correctly, or not at all to be precise. The loss you print out is just from the last batch. This explains why the results differ when using shuffle. This should definitely not be the case when implemented correctly.

The fact that you get a negative loss is because you just use the mean of the logits as loss, which of course can be negative.

Still other metrics like accuracy should not be affected by this, but you didn't provide the code that calculates those metrics, so theres no way of spotting the point of failure.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally put the wrong code in. I was normally adding all the loss values from each batch together. I updated the code snippet for that part and the rsulting loss is still negative (-0,15). As for metrics, I get the same loss value from both dataloader objects. I also added the metric code at the bottom. I'm not sure if I should add the part where I transform the logits to the actual values tho? I feel like it's just unnecessary to add into the post. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Also there is no particular reason why i'm getting the mean of the loss. It's just what I saw from all other notebooks for evaluation step.

Comment: I added another update for loss value. It seems to work fine now but I still haven't got an answer for DataLoader problem. @ValeKnappich